# Cube/ Roll up Function of dataframe but to skip the summing of a column for few records in spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a following dataframe:

```
+--------+------+---------+---------+
|  Col1  | col2 | values1 | Values2 |
+--------+------+---------+---------+
| item1  | A1   |       5 |      11 |
| item1  | A2   |       5 |      25 |
| item1  | A3   |       5 |      33 |
| item1  | na   |         |      18 |
| item2  | A1   |       6 |      12 |
| item2  | A2   |       6 |      26 |
| item2  | A3   |       6 |      34 |
| item2  | na   |       6 |         |
+--------+------+---------+---------+
```

which can be created with this code

```
df = Seq(
        (item1, A1,5 ,11),
        (item1, A2,5 ,25),
        (item1, A3,5 ,33),
        (item1, na,0,18),
        (item2, A1,6 ,12),
        (item2, A2,6 ,26),
        (item2, A3,6 ,34),
        (item2, na,6 ,0)).toDF('Col1', 'col2', 'values1', 'Values2');
```

I want to skip the adding of column values1 for all the records when doing rollup or cube on it.

**My Desired OutPut:**

```
+-------+------+---------+---------+
| Col1  | col2 | values1 | values2 |
+-------+------+---------+---------+
| null  | null |      17 |     159 |
| item1 | null |       5 |      87 |
| item1 | A1   |       5 |      11 |
| item1 | A2   |       5 |      25 |
| item1 | A3   |       5 |      33 |
| item1 | na   |       0 |      18 |
| item2 | null |      12 |      72 |
| item2 | A1   |       6 |      12 |
| item2 | A2   |       6 |      26 |
| item2 | A3   |       6 |      34 |
| item2 | na   |       6 |         |
+-------+------+---------+---------+
```

How can I get a rollup or cube Function applied to this dataset so that sum of values1 to Col1 should sum up the values for either (A1/A2/A3)+na=
so for eg:

the second row shows

**values1** *=5= 5+0* and **values2**= *87=11+25+33+18*  and the  6th row 
**values1** *=12=6+6* and **values2** *=12+26+34+0=72*

But what I get now by doing the rollup operation is 
Adds up all the agg which I don't want to happen for **values1** column.

```
df.rollup("Col1","col2").agg(sum("values1") as "values1",sum("values2") as "values2");
```

**Current Output:**

```
+-------+------+---------+---------+
| Col1  | col2 | values1 | values2 |
+-------+------+---------+---------+
| null  | null |      39 |     159 |
| item1 | null |      15 |      87 |
| item1 | A1   |       5 |      11 |
| item1 | A2   |       5 |      25 |
| item1 | A3   |       5 |      33 |
| item1 | na   |       0 |      18 |
| item2 | null |      24 |      72 |
| item2 | A1   |       6 |      12 |
| item2 | A2   |       6 |      26 |
| item2 | A3   |       6 |      34 |
| item2 | na   |       6 |         |
+-------+------+---------+---------+
```

(The link which was posted as dup is not the actual ask here. The desired output is different than the answers in the link )

Comment: I'd give solutions a try. Please don't delete and repost again rather edit the same question. PS: Dupe flags are not a punishment.

Comment: No Eliasah. That question was completely shuffled up. I should ve re edited. Yeah.

Comment: If you consider that the links don't help, you can comment and we will see how we might be able to help or maybe I'll re-open the question.

Comment: @eliasah. Sure. Will consider all these going forward. Thanks for bringing it up.

Comment: @eliasah The links which you have marked as duplicate is definitely different thing than what I have asked as desired output. Can you please look  at the desired output once and the link answers.

Comment: I'll try to take a look at this later. I'll re-open the question meanwhile.

Comment: @eliasah ok thank you